# jQuery attr() not returning in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, attr

This one has me stumped.  I'm using the "for" attribute on some links to identify the element they're supposed to act on.  Everything seems to be working just fine in Firefox, IE9, and IE8 ... but IE7 breaks and returns "undefined."

Here's the gist of the jQuery code I'm using:

```
$(document.ready(function() {
    var editor_icons = $('.edit-button');

    editor_icons.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            parent = $('#' + $this.attr('for'));

        var left = parent.position().left + parent.innerWidth() - 58 - 3,
            top = parent.position().top + 3;

        // ... you get the point ...
    });
});
```

An example HTML element this should be acting on:

```
<div id="content_wrapper">
    <a class="edit-button" href="javascript:void(0);" for="index_primary_content" />
    <div id="index_primary_content">
        ....
    </div>
</div>
```

> *Before you point it out, I realize anchors aren't supposed to be auto-closing elements.  The HTML I'm sending from my application is `<a></a>` and IE is interpreting it as `<a />`.  I added a `&nbsp;` in between the elements to make sure it wasn't an interpretation issue, and I get the exact same error.*

The problem is that `$this.attr('for')` returns "undefined", so `parent.position().left` throws an "object is null or undefined" error.

I dug down with watch variables a bit, and I can see that the selectors are working, and `$this` in this context does select the right elements and does have the "for" attribute set ... but jQuery isn't finding it I think.

As I said, it works just fine in Firefox, IE9, and IE8 ... just not IE7.  Ideas?

For reference, I'm using jQuery 1.6.2 ...

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use the `for`? Have you tried perhaps giving the `<a>` and its corresponding `<div>` the same class and finding it that way?

Comment: This is an ASP.Net MVC project.  The anchor link is created dynamically using a reusable control - I map the anchor to the ID of the element it links to, but the control doesn't know what classes are in use. There are other ways I could do this, yes, but custom attributes were easiest and seem to work everywhere else.

Comment: Then give it a different name. Instead of `for` use `target_ele` or something else, it should still work. Your editor will yell at you but it should work.

Comment: Jack, post that as a solution.  It's not ideal ... but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `for` use a custom attribute instead; `target_ele` for example.

Your editor will yell at you, but it will work.

Comment: Decided to use "parent" for my custom attribute since it was germane to what I was doing.  I'd still like to know why "for" is disallowed.  It's a valid attribute with other HTML elements, so why does jQuery restrict it to only labels?  I guess that's a question for another day ...

Comment: Use `data-for` for HTML5 custom attributes.

Comment: Also, "for" isn't disallowed ... see my comment on @Hexxagonal's answer for an explanation as to why this doesn't work for IE7.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is your issue [jQuery Bug Ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6392)

> This is because the "for" property when used in HTML is actually "htmlFor", for example in the label element. That would be true of any of the special cases in jQuery.props I suspect. XML documents don't get this special treatment so "for" would be "for" there. I'm not sure whether this is worth fixing, or just documenting.

Comment: It turns out that "for" translates to "htmlFor" in everything *but* IE7.  I poked around at the actual `.attr()` extension and it automatically converts "for" to "htmlFor" before checking `.getAttribute()`.  In my case `.getAttribute('for')` returned the right value, but `.getAttribute('htmlFor')` returns `null` ... so jQuery returns `undefined.`